# Matplotlib graph with multiple y axis shows and doesn't save

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a graph with 3 y axis, and it shows in the plot window of Spyder instead of saving correctly in a folder. The graph saved in a folder is blank.
Here's my code :

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
plt.figure(figsize = (121, 75))

ax1.set_xlabel('time(s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('y1')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2')
ax3.set_ylabel('y3')
rspine = ax3.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.15))
plt.xticks(fontsize=50)
plt.yticks(fontsize=50)
ax1.plot(fd[fd.columns[0]], fd[fd.columns[1]], color = 'r', linewidth = 2)
ax2.plot(fd[fd.columns[0]], fd[fd.columns[2]], color = 'g', linewidth = 2)
ax3.plot(fd[fd.columns[0]], fd[fd.columns[3]], color = 'b', linewidth = 2)
ax3.legend([ax1.get_lines()[0], ax2.get_lines()[0], ax3.get_lines()[0]], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
plt.savefig(folder+"/"+str(file_name)+"y1/2/3.png")
plt.close()
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? I don't call the `show()` function so I don't understand why the graph shows anyway (when plotting the 3 y axis on the same graph with only using `plt.figure()`, `plt.plot()` then `plt.save()` and `close()`, it works as intended)

Edit : What I want is to have the graph saved correctly in my folder, with the size I set in `plt.figure()`, which isn't the case now.

Comment: Does `fig.savefig(folder+"/"+str(file_name)+"y1/2/3.png")` work?

Comment: I don't know how to stop showing the graph

Comment: That saved the graph in the forlder, but the size doesn't correspond to what I put in plt.figure(), even if I change the values in there

Comment: To stop displaying plots, use ````plt.ioff()```` assuming plt is matplotlib.pyplot somewhere at the start of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what went wrong :
I stead of writing
`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(121, 75)) fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()`,
I had to write
`fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(121, 75))`
The graph then plots at the size indicated, and doesn't shows in the window of Spyder.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `set_size_inches` before saving the figure. `dpi` feature can be use to increase the resolution of the figure also.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '50'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(121, 75), dpi=200)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('time(s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('y1')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2')
ax3.set_ylabel('y3')
rspine = ax3.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.05))
rspine2 = ax2.spines['right']
rspine2.set_position(('axes', 1.0))
# plt.xticks(fontsize=50)
# plt.yticks(fontsize=50)
ax1.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.rand(100), color='r', linewidth=2)
ax2.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.rand(100), color='g', linewidth=2)
ax3.plot(np.arange(100), np.random.rand(100), color='b', linewidth=2)
ax3.legend([ax1.get_lines()[0], ax2.get_lines()[0], ax3.get_lines()[0]], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'])
# fig.tight_layout()
figure = plt.gcf()
figure.set_size_inches(121, 75)
plt.savefig("3.png", dpi=None)
plt.close()
```

Comment: The graph doesn't show, it just says in the console ```<Figure size 17474.8x10800 with 0 Axes>```, but the graph saved has a size that is not the one I set

Comment: I'm sorry I left the `plt.show()`. If you remove it, that's print the figure in the file

Comment: There is no `plt.show()`in my code and your answer

Comment: I see. I didn't undersood your question right. if you use the `set_size_inches` just before the `savefile`function it will save the file with the correct size

Comment: That saved the graph, but only only one of the two y axis on the right appears, and the size set in `plt.figure()` isn't in inches, so I gotta find the values for the graph to be the same size

Comment: I edited my minimal example, I have both axis to the right y2 and y3. I put the font size in the `plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '50'` directly